# directx 11 c++ application in vs 2012 -- full screen crashes after running for a while

Tags: windows, directx

Win7 Directx 11 with VS 2012 -- When I let my app run in full screen on my development computer, eventually, the program exits full screen back to windowed, all by itself, and pops up a dialog telling me windows resources are running low. The dialog tells me something about turning off interactive themes or something to that end. When I run the program in release mode on one of our client machines, the app runs fine, does everything it should, but after a while, instead of popping up the dialog about windows resources, I get an exception window with exception 0x40000015 as the error. This only happens if I am in full screen, windowed, it never crashes. Event Viewer shows nothing at all about the crash. Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance. Basically what my app is, is a wrapper graphics library. When it says I am using all the resources, my resource monitor shows that I never went above 20% of memory and the cpu never went above 14%. The 0x40000015 error number is rather general and doesn't exactly point me in any real direction.

This is not related to trying to exit an app in full screen, as that I have the code required to prevent the exception related to that problem.

R

Comment: Example code of your attempts so far would be helpful

Comment: You probably have a resource leak. See [Direct3D SDK Debug Layer Tricks](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/11/30/direct3d-sdk-debug-layer-tricks.aspx) for some suggestions, particularly ``ReportLiveDeviceObjects``

Comment: We got the ReportLiveDeviceObjects working Chuck, thanks for that. Still haven't solved it. It only crashes on that one platform. Beginning to think the crash is being brought on from some other component on the WES7 embedded drive or the lack thereof. On multiple other Win7 machines it never crashes. Had some issues with the windows composition resource dialog knocking it out of fullscreen, but after disabling that no more of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a component issue on the target platform. The ReportLiveDeviceObjects info was helpful and will continue to help down the line.